# Relational database design: One-to-many connection - Is storing a customer ID as part of an order ID too redundant?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, one-to-many, redundancy

I am new to relational database design. At the moment I try to setup a one-to-many relationship as clean as possible.

I have two tables: Customers & Orders. Every customer gets a public ID assigned which looks like this: `ABC`. Every order gets a public ID assigned which looks like this: `ABC-123`. So you see, the first part of the order number is the customer number.

One rule I've learned is that every piece of data should only be stored *once*. Storing the order number like `ABC-123` would introduce a bit of redundancy because `ABC` is already stored & every order is connected with the customer using a *unique foreign key*.

So actually, it could make sense to only store `123` as order number and build the public ID (`ABC-123`) dynamically if an output in an application is needed.

Is this right or am I too strict regarding redundancy?

Comment: Seems that you're discussing order "123" of customer "ABC" while there may be a different order "123" of customer "DEF"? These orders "ABC-123" and "DEF-123" can be distinguished using additional internal IDs, such as perhaps 173250 and 173251.

Comment: @ajm475du Yep of course - every entry has it's own unique primary key for that matter. I am just wondering what the best way is to save the public id (that is e.g. sent to the user) in the database. Thats why I noticed the redundancy and had the idea to build the public id dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every order gets a public ID assigned which looks like this: ABC-123. So you see, the first part of the order number is the customer number.

By storing customer ID as **part** of another field, you are actually violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity), and therefore the 1NF.

> So actually, it could make sense to only store 123 as order number and build the public ID (ABC-123) dynamically if an output in an application is needed.

Yes, that's what you should do. You could even construct the "public ID" in a VIEW if multiple clients need it.

As a general rule of thumb: database is for storing data, not formatting it. So you should store the data in a way that makes most sense at the logical level, and leave presentation to other layers of code...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, good to know I was on the right track ;-)